# With which method has Apple replaced "dragImage:"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, swift, nsview

I have an app where I allow the user to drag/drop some data from an NSView, with a custom drag image under the cursor.

I just updated to the Xcode 6 beta, and now my drag/drop code won't compile. This is because **Apple has deprecated the following NSView method**:

> dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:

Fine, but what am I supposed to use instead? All the Apple documentation I've found still merrily recommends the deprecated method.

There is also a "dragFile:" method, however my NSView represents AV data, and it's unsuitable to write a large new file to disk every time the user begins a drag. The user may well to abort the drag, possibly multiple times in rapid succession.

**What is the new way to initiate a drag operation with a custom icon?**

Comment: Ask that at Apple's forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kyle Sluder on Apple's Dev forums for alerting me to this. It turns out the replacement is

[NSView beginDraggingSessionWithItems: event: source:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/beginDraggingSessionWithItems%3aevent%3asource%3a)